# Django testing hangs with --keepdb flag

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

For performance tuning reasons, I want to run Django tests against a copy of my production database.  As I understand it, this should be possible by:

(1) adjusting Django settings like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'my_database_copy',
        },
    }
}
```

and (2) using the `--keepdb` flag, as in `python manage.py test --keepdb`.[1]

But when I do this, the process hangs, looking like this:

```
bash-4.2$ python manage.py test --keepdb
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
```

(The process won't close with `ctrl+c`.  I'm using Docker, and I stop it by restarting Docker.)

There are no unapplied migrations for the database, and the test command (`python manage.py test`) works fine, if `--keepdb` is omitted.

I confirmed that the database copy is properly restored and accessible because I can access it when I run `python manage.py shell`.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#preserving-the-test-database

Comment: Does the test database get deleted if you don't use `--keepdb`?

Comment: @Ben 
If I omit the `--keepdb` flag, then the test process identifies that the `database “my_database_copy” already exists`, and asks if the process should delete it.  If I input “no”, the test process exists (naturally).  If I input “yes”, the tests run successfully.  If I then run `python manage.py shell`, I can confirm that the database has been deleted, `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: database “my_database_copy” does not exist`.

Comment: Interesting, does running with debug-mode tell you anything https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-debug-mode `python manage.py test --keepdb --debug-mode`

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your help.  I believe I was able to resolve the issue through changing the `SERIALIZE` setting.  See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the settings dictionary by adding the `SERIALIZE` key, like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'my_database_copy',
            'SERIALIZE': False,
        },
    }
}
```

When `SERIALIZE` is `True` (the default), Django tries to read a copy of the whole database into memory as a string.  See[1].  This considered helpful for tests when the database engine does not support transactions, but in my case crashed due to insufficient memory.  Deactivating this behavior through settings is covered here[2].

[1] https://github.com/django/django/blob/d5b526bf78a9e5d9760e0c0f7647622bf47782fe/django/db/backends/base/creation.py#L73

[2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#serialize